# useEffect code is showing wrong info even when backend has returned correct data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React and came across below tricky issue,  in below code output is as below

**IN  3**

**HERE 0**

Per my understanding `setVideos` has set value for `Videos` array then why is the length returned is 0 ?

```
const [Videos, setVideos] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/video/getVideos')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log("IN  " + response.data.videos.length)
                setVideos(response.data.videos)
                console.log("HERE " + Videos.length);
            } else {
                console.log("OUT");
                alert('Failed to get Videos')
            }
        })
}, [])
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous in React. You can't `console.log` them on the next line. Print it outside the `useEffect`

Comment: have a read at this - it should hopefully clear up some things you may be wondering about - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In React, state changes are **asynchronous** and can't be logged just after they are set. I made this example to make it more clear for you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setVideos(["A", "B", "C", "D"]);
    console.log("Videos1:", videos); //----> empty
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Videos:", videos); //---> REAL values
  }, [videos])

  const displayVideos = videos.map((elem, index) => 
    <div key={index}>
      <h1>{elem}</h1>
    </div>
  )

  return (
    <div>
    {displayVideos}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w8st8w)

Answer (score -1):

The general problem is that we want to wait for a state update an then do something afterward. Unfortunately, we can not write sequential code, because every state update is asynchronous.
With a custom hook - namely useStateWithPromise - this problem can be solved.

Comment: no need for custom hooks here